# Loading spinner while loading data from API into a ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i am fetching data from internet and displaying it in a ListView , the data loading takes a little bit time at first and i want to add a loading spinner while the data loades . This is the ListView :

```
            Expanded(
                child:
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:this.data.length ,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return _specialistsCardInfo() ;
                    }
                )
            ),
```

how and where can i add a loading spinner here ?

Comment: Use FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a stateful widget.

```dart
class CardsPage extends StatefulWidget {
   //.....
}

class CardsPageState extends State<CardsPage> {
  bool isLoading = true;

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    // Code to fetch your data
    await ...
    // Finished fetching data
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Call the fetch data method
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build() {
    return isLoading ? 
       Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : 
       Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
             itemCount:this.data.length ,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _specialistsCardInfo() ;
             }
           )
        );
    }
}
```

**How it works**

`isLoading = true` so when we enter the page, we'll see the loading spinner.
After fetching the data, we `setState` `isLoading = false` so the `build()` method returns your ListView instead of the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this! `data.list` means it is your data!

```
if(data.list == null) CircularProgressIndicator(),
Expanded(
                child:
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:this.data.length ,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return _specialistsCardInfo() ;
                    }
                )
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a bool and name it as `isLoading`, by default the value of the bool is **false** and set the value to **true** when you hit the api and as soon as your get the result, set `isLoading` to **false**.
Lets code:

```
bool isLoading = false;

isLoading
? CircularProgressIndicator
: Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: this.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _specialistsCardInfo();
      },
    ),
  );
```

**Get Data from Api:**

```
myMethod(context){
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    //Hit Api

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    // Api Response is here

  }
```

Comment: This is great! But you can just set `isLoading = true` by default so that you can avoid the first `setState`. Then the widget will just rebuild once instead of twice.

Comment: Thank you so much Akora but i prefer to make default isLoading = false so that by default it's always false. Only when the api hits, its true. :)